# Setting element height/width to a combination of percent and pixel values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the jQuery .css() method to set the `height` and `width` of an element to 30% of the container `div` element minus 10 pixels.  How would I do this?

Here is my attempt:

```
$('div').css({
    height:'30%-5px';
});
```

Comment: Step 1: show us what you tried.

Comment: Edited my post to show my gut attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CSS3, you can use `calc()`:

```
$('div').css({
    height: 'calc(30%-5px)';
});
```

Note that this has [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility). Considering finding a value that can be used as a fallback (such as `height: 29%`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the CSS `calc()` function, eg:

```
$('div').css({
    height: 'calc(30% - 5px)';
});
```